# Speech Recognition or msconfig without elevation in C++

Tags: c++, windows, process, speech-recognition, createprocess

I've been trying to make a program that uses `CreateProcess()` to run windows Speech Recognition on Windows 8.1. Upon creating a process, I get the error 740 (needs to be elevated). But when I run speech recognition as a standard user (either by calling `C:\Windows\Speech\Common\sapisvr.exe -SpeechUX` in cmd, or by opening it in Ease of Access center), there is no prompt asking me for elevating to admin rights. Why does it ask for it when I try to create the same process programatically? Is there a workaround for it? I need it to work for any standard user.

```
//This invokes SR without any problem, as well as manually typing into cmd
system("C:\\Windows\\Speech\\Common\\sapisvr.exe -SpeechUX");

//This returns error if not run as admin
TCHAR[] param = TEXT("-SpeechUX");
if (!CreateProcess(TEXT("C:\\Windows\\Speech\\Common\\sapisvr.exe"),
                   param,NULL,NULL,FALSE,0,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi))
{
    printf("error creating process %d", GetLastError());
    return 1;
}
```

The same happens when trying to invoke msconfig.exe. I know that msconfig needs more privilege, but as far as I know, it should be runable by anyone, and it should ask for admin consent during the runtime (when clicking on one of its tabs). But using CreateProcess() I am unable to even invoke the process itself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An executable that is marked as "requireAdministrator" in its manifest cannot be started from a non-elevated process using `CreateProcess()`. Instead, ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED will be returned. `ShellExecute()` or `ShellExecuteEx()` must be used instead.
The `runas` verb is used to launch programs that need elevated user rights. In your case, you have rights, but program doesn't have. ShellExecute give you more rights.

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "runas", "C:\\Windows\\Speech\\Common\\sapisvr.exe", param, 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Documentation of [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Starting a speech recognition with `ShellExecute` still prompts me with admin dialog.

Comment: In fact, running `ShellExecute` with second param `"runas"` makes a standard user require admin password, but running it with second param `NULL` doesn't. Msconfig can't be launched either way. I guess it is impossible to run it without prompt now.